# Axios request not firing on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a `componentdidMount` and in there we have a Axios request. When de the development server has compiled we don't see the get request back.

```
componentDidMount () {
         axios({
             method: 'get',
             baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
             url: 'isp/',
             headers: authHeader(),
             Accept: 'application/json'
         }).then(
             function(response) {
                 console.log(response)
             }
         ).catch(
             function(error) {
                 console.log(error)
             }
         )
     }
```

[Network example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktoTU.png)

Comment: what is `Accept` option in axios? It should be a part of headers or `responseType: 'json'`

Comment: What if you migrate to hooks?